# How to measure speed of parcelable vs serializable

Tags: java, android, performance, serialization, parcelable

I need to perform a metric measurement on the speed of serialization vs parcelable in Android. I have a very large POJO object that gson converts to JSON and vice versa.

But my superiors would like a metric to determine if  converting our serializable classes to parcelable android classes is worth the effort. They dont want to hear community based opinions.  What are the best tools i can use to measure the timing ? What do you think about using Android's traceview ?

Comment: First google result for 'parceable vs serializable android' http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't need to do perf test, serialisation uses reflection and parcelable not. This means more your object is big, more it will take time to reflect it.

Comment: i surely agree with you but my company is asking for a metric.

Comment: Serialization actually doesn't need to use reflection. It's capable of doing the same manual non-reflection process that Parcelable does, which means it's capable of being just as fast. https://bitbucket.org/afrishman/androidserializationtest